# S3 Policy Limiting Access to only one foler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket, amazon-iam

I have a bucket in S3 named home, and have multiple folders under it.  I want to allow a specific user to be able to access to the folder1 under path: home/A/B/folder1. However I do not want him to see any other buckets and even other folders in this home bucket.

Can anyone help me with this policy?

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) provides several [User Policy Examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html) and the desired scenario is explored in [Example: Allow each IAM user access to a folder in a bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex1):

> In this example, you want two IAM users, Alice and Bob, to have access to your bucket, examplebucket, so they can add, update, and delete objects. However, you want to restrict each user’s access to a single folder in the bucket.

As explained there, you can attach individual policies per user, however, it is meanwhile best addressed by using [IAM Policy Variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html):

> Instead of attaching policies to individual users, though, you can
>   write a single policy that uses a policy variable and attach the
>   policy to a group. [...] The following example policy allows a set of
>   Amazon S3 permissions in the examplebucket/${aws:username} folder.
>   When the policy is evaluated, the policy variable ${aws:username} is
>   replaced by the requester's user name. [...]
>
> ```js
> {
>    "Version":"2012-10-17",
>    "Statement":[
>       {
>          "Effect":"Allow",
>          "Action":[
>             "s3:PutObject",
>             "s3:GetObject",
>             "s3:GetObjectVersion",
>             "s3:DeleteObject",
>             "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
>          ],
>          "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/${aws:username}/*"
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```